# cannot return document.querySelector with nightmare API on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide, nightmare

I am using [nightmare.js](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api) for web scripting on a Chinese e-commerce website taobao(www.taobao.com/). The goal is to get product information. The code is very similar to the [yahoo example code](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api) but the result is always null. I tried to put console.log to debug and realized the mistake might lay in the querySelector.
Below is the code if someone has the time to take a look. Really appreciate it.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
  .goto('https://www.taobao.com')
  .type('form[action*="/search"] [name=q]', 'hellow kitty')
  .click('form[action*="/search"] [type=submit]')
  .wait(2000)
  .evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector('.row.row-2.title a')
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Just tried going to that website and doing a search for `hello kitty`,.. there is nothing on there with a `.row` or even `.row-2` class.  But if i do `document.querySelectorAll('.item')` this will give you all the products on the page if that's what your after.

Comment: Use screenshot() to see what was rendered on the target page at the time of executing evaluate. That should give you fair idea if the element you are trying read exist or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost: double-check your selectors and make sure they exist.

Setting that aside, the issue lay with `return document.querySelector('.row.row-2.title a')`.  DOM lists (like those returned from `document.querySelector`) do not serialize nicely.  Try pulling the results you want out before returning - say you wanted the HREFs from the anchors, you could do something like (from the hip):

```
return Array.from(document.querySelector('.row.row-2.title a')).map(a=> a.href);
```